# Colocar uma imagem.jpg como plano de fundo maximizada

Tags: java, html, css

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stilo.css">
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Gleriston</title>
<body background="images.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat" background>

<h2>Sua viagem comeca aqui</h2>


<div align="center"> Login:<input type="text" name="nome"> </div><br>
<div align="center"> Senha:<input type="text" name="nome1"> <br> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Entrar"></div>


<div id="nav">

</div>

<div id="section">

</div><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="footer">
Copyright © Gleriston.com
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui e o CSS:

```
<style>
#bg{

}

#header {

}
#nav {

}
#section {

}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: che, Gleison, como é que vc posta um troço assim e vai embora??? Demonstra muito pouco interesse... :(

Comment: OI,minha net esta ruim,desculpas,moral da historia estou usando jsp,html e css pra ser mais claro quero colocar uma imagem maximizada,dessa forma so conseguir colocar ela no canto esquerdo do monitor a imagem esta no meu projeto.Desconsiderem o background depois do no-repeat,ele foi sem querer mais em fim alguem pode dar um apoio.

Comment: Como o problema é de CSS e HTML, e não de Java, provavelmente a resposta de cima serve.